# Centering text in .epub files, whatever it takes

Tags: text, centering, epub

I'm an absolute beginner and way over my head in html stuff. I've read tutorials, watched videos, and figured I had the basics down but, try as I might, am completely unable to center text in .epub files, specifically using Sigil.

So far, I've tried:

Number 1:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Test</p>
```

This seems to work in the Sigil program, but whenever I export the file and open it with .epub readers, the text is not centered.

Number 2:
Using a .css file to define styles. In .css file:

```
c1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then I use the text:

```
<c1>Test</c1>
```

I've tried using .class or <span>, but it doesn't work, either

The odd thing is, if I were to modify the font size, it would work like a charm; it's just centering the text that doesn't work, no matter what I try.

All I want to do is center text. Whatever works is fine.